# My Custom Classes didn't complie when i build the project in MVC.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

we create some classes outside of the View,Model & Controller in our MVC project.
when we build it, there should be some error in the classes we made but it build successfully and do not show any error. so the errors appear in run time mode(when browser show up).
(for example i put some error in my custom class like some unassigned variable but it doesn't give me any error on compile time). so in develop step we can not easily solve our errors.
any help?

here is my solution image:

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using batis_blog.Commponent;
using batis_blog.Models;
using batis_blog.SystemProperty;

namespace batis_blog.UserServics
{

public class UserServic:DBMan
{
  public DBmessage Edit()
    {
        SqlConnection newcon = new SqlConnection(SystemStatic.g);
        SqlCommand newcmd = new SqlCommand("UserEdit", newcon);
        newcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        ///
        SqlParameter _oldcardno = new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int);
        _oldcardno.Value = this.UserID;
        SqlParameter _username = new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        _username.Value = this.Username;
        SqlParameter _name = new SqlParameter("@Fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        _name.Value = this.Fname;
        SqlParameter _family = new SqlParameter("@Lname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        _family.Value = this.Lname;
        newcmd.Parameters.Add(_oldcardno);
        newcmd.Parameters.Add(_name);
        newcmd.Parameters.Add(_family);
        newcon.Open();
        newcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        newcon.Close();
    }
   }
}
namespace batis_blog.Commponent
{
    public class DBMan
    {

    protected SqlConnection conn;
    protected SqlCommand cmd;
    protected SqlDataAdapter da;
    protected DataTableBatis dt;
    protected DBMan()
    {


        string strconn = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SahebDB"].ConnectionString;

        conn = new SqlConnection(strconn);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect compiler to catch all possible errors, including runtime ones?

Comment: Can you please confirm that the class you are created is another file or in already used file ????? –

Comment: here is my solution image :http://batisapp.ir/image/Capture.PNG

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear.  Can you show the definition of UserService class?  Clearly, there is a UserID property of field, or it would not compile (unless it's an Expando object).  You mention a "runtime error", what is the exact error message?

Comment: Sometimes, clearing temporary asp.net files, cleaning solution and rebuilding solution works like a charm!

Comment: can you show some actual code here that we can examine rather than just a screenshot? I can think of 5 things I would check, but I can't do anything from a screenshot.

Comment: please attention that UserID is a property that doesn't defined in UserServic.cs but when i write this.UserID it should give me compile error and after build project as you see in that pic  there is no error. the error appears in run time

Comment: Yes, we get that, but we don't believe you.  Please show us your actual User Service code, including any base classes it may derive from.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch i put cod on post

Comment: @user2668753 - this is obviously not all the code, since there are other variables there as well that you don't show.  Have you right clicked on them in Visual Studio and selected Go To Definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have not included the file in the project.

Right click on the file in solution explorer and select include in project

Comment: How your answer is relevant to OP's question? Have you read the question?

Comment: Yes, Once a file is created outside of the project, for compile it in the project , it should be added in the project. Since it is not added in project , at compile time it doesn't show any errors, but it shows runtime error since this has dependency.

Comment: I see no any "files outside of project" mentioned in question. I see OP said only about classes "outside of the View,Model & Controller". So this definitely needs to be clarified.

Comment: Can you please confirm that the class you are created is another file or in already used file ?????

Comment: my files are in the project and all of them is include too